# Navigate to and learn all the web objects on a page using Java (without Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium, web, automation

I work for a start-up, where we have a requirement to automatically navigate to a given web application and find out information about all the objects contained within a page (inclusive of any iframes inside). We are supposed to code this module in Java.

So, I used Selenium WebDriver and was successful. However, due to some reasons, we've been asked not to use Selenium, but rather Core Java to do this.

So here's my question. Let's say I want to open "http://www.google.co.in" on my Firefox browser, and I have to get the attribute values for the Search Textbox, Search button and I'm feeling Lucky button. I have to do this using Java. Where do I start?

I had an idea, which was to actually navigate to a page, read its HTML source and build an xpath query to find each element and get its attributes. But how do I accomplish this navigation using Java (or jQuery as well, if that's possible)?

It may sound as if I'm trying to build an automation tool from the scratch, but I'm just considering all possibilities.

Please help.

Comment: Are you confusing Java and JavaScript? They're completely different languages and environments. In particular the statement *"...how do I accomplish this navigation using Java (or jQuery as well..."* suggests confusion.

Comment: Its sounds more like you are trying to build a new version of `Selenium` from scratch...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm sorry I sounded confused. But actually, I would like to know if it can be done in either Core Java, or JavaScript.

Comment: @radimpe Ha ha.. it sounds like that I know :)., but the scope is limited to reading the screen. In other words, another version of firebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have loaded the HTML content of the page into a single string variable, you can use standard Java string mechanisms to find contents of the HTML page in your string.

Comment: Thank you, but my question pertains to the first step. I need to invoke the browser (or activate an open browser) and get the HTML content of the page. And I have to use Java or JavaScript (jQuery). I know I can use selenium WebDriver api to get the page's HTML content, but that is something I am forbidden to use.

Comment: Not necessarily, you could use Apache HTTP Components (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) to obtain the HTML code from a given URL.

Comment: I appreciate your help. It was useful. I found out a way to extract the HTML and load them to a file, and am now trying to extract ifnormation about all the controls on the page. Though at this stage my code looks filthy, I hope with some more tweaks here and there I should be getting along the right track. Thank you for your help, it did open up a door for me.

Answer (score 0):

This might help http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077567/core-java/java-tip-66--control-browsers-from-your-java-application.html
Don't know why you want to do in Java instead of Selenium. Selenium will  be the best tool for this job, you should convince your team instead.